# How to get Java Glassfish App From Netbeans to a Free Standing Online Application

Tags: java, jsp, web

I have developed a web application for a relative. It's my first project, and I spent a long time learning Java JSP technology to complete it. My question is: How do I deploy this web application so that my relative has it in an online server. It's an order management system that she wants to be able to pull up online whenever se is taking orders with clients, so it needs to be connected to a web server somehow and accessible through WIFI. I have tried to research it but just keep getting confused. Any step by step instructions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your web application, you should end up with a `.war` (**w**eb **ar**chive) file.

You need to run the application in a container or application server. NetBeans does this when you run your application, it has a Glassfish instance and it deploys your application to it.

To run your application in your own Glassfish instance:

- install [Glassfish](https://glassfish.java.net/)
- login to the Glassfish server (`http://localhost:4848`, `admin`/`admin` are the default address and username/password)
- setup the database connection
- create a JDBC Connection Pool

  - go to `Resources` > `JDBC` > `JDBC Connection Pools`
  - click on `New`
  - enter a `Pool Name` (can be anything, but remember it)
  - set `Resource Type` to `javax.sql.DataSource`
  - set `Database Driver Vendor` to the database that you are using (i.e. `Postgresql`)
  - Click `Next`
  - scroll down to `Additional Properties`
  - enter the URL for your database (i.e `jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/my-database`)
  - enter the `driverClass` for your database (i.e. `org.postgresql.Driver`)
  - enter the `serverName` (i.e. `hostname`), the `databaseName` (i.e. `my-database`) and the `portNumber` (i.e. `5432`)
  - enter the `username` and `password` for the database
- create a JDBC Resource

  - go to `Resources` > `JDBC` > `JDBC Resource`
  - enter the `JNDI Name` (this is what you refer to in your application)
  - enter the `Pool Name` of the JDBC Connection Pool that you created in the previous step
- now you can deploy your application
- go to `Applications`
- click on `Deploy`
- locate your `.war` file (browse your machine, or copy it to the target machine and browse local)
- enter the `Context Root` (this forms the last part of your application URL, i.e. `/my-application`)
- enter the `Application Name` (you might use the Application Name if you do any manual EJB lookups, make sure it matches in that case)
- click on `OK` to deploy your application
- it's a good idea to watch the logs as you deploy for any error messages, they are located at (`/glassfish/install/path/glassfish/domain/domain1/logs/server.log`)
- once your application is deployed, there is a link on the `Applications` page called `Launch` if you click that you will get the URL for your application (i.e. `http://localhost:8080/my-application`)

I dare say you might have more questions, some of these steps are fairly involved.

To expose your application to the world, you need an internet facing web server and knowledge of how to administer it and how to handle all of the security concerns.

There are other options too. Platforms like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) and [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine) will host your Java application and save you the hassle of administering a web server, but you have to design your application to use technologies that they provide. Worth thinking about perhaps.